# Learning ajax. How to print the variable on json response

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, laravel

I am trying to learn ajax, because it will be useful for the project I am developing. I am only getting started at it. I've watched some tutorials and now I testing out some code. I am using laravel. Here is my view:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="getRequest">get Request</button>
    <div id="teste"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var id = 12; // A random variable for this example

$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  }
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#getRequest').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
    method: 'POST', // Type of response and matches what we said in the route
    url: '/customer/ajaxupdate', // This is the url we gave in the route
    data: {'id' : id}, // a JSON object to send back
    success: function(response){ // What to do if we succeed
        var theDiv = document.getElementById("teste");theDiv.innerHTML += response->'teste'; 
        console.log(response); 
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { // What to do if we fail
        console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
        console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
    }
    });
    })
})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AjaxController extends Controller
{
    public function updateCustomerRecord(Request $request)
    {
        $datda = $request->all(); // This will get all the equest data.
        $teste = "teste";
        return response()->json(['success' => true, 'teste' => $teste]);
        echo "ole";
    }
}
```

And lastly we have my routes:

```
Route::post('/customer/ajaxupdate', 'AjaxController@updateCustomerRecord');
Route::get('/teste', function(){
    return view('teste');
});
```

As you can see this is simple code... When I get more used to Ajax I will do a select from database and show data on the view. But now I am trying to pass data from one variable on the controller to the view using json response. I also wish you could give me a tip how I should do a simple db:select and the best way to pass it through to the view.

I am expecting this code to pass data from controller to view.

Comment: What is the code doing and what did you expect it to do? Any console errors? PHP Errors?

Comment: Your echo will never be reachd btw

Comment: @mplungjan I am expecting this code to pass data from controller to view.

Comment: @mplungjan and I want to know how I can echo the variable $teste.

Comment: If you really want to learn AJAX I would recommend you to learn XMLHttpRequest (XHR) before using any kind of library (like jQuery, which is, by the way, slowly declining) and before using any new API like Fetch or Beacon. Please note that this is a friendly recommendation.

Comment: @ErnestoStifano Appreciated your help, and your recommendation, I will follow that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a mistake in your `JavaScript` code. You are using  arrow `->` instead of period or dot `.`

**Please replace this**

```
theDiv.innerHTML += response->'teste';
```

**with this**

```
theDiv.innerHTML = response.teste;
```

Comment: You are welcome. Please don't forget to accept the answer.